# Normal vector to plane centered between two points

Tags: math, vector

I have two points (P1, P3) in a 3D coordinate system as shown in the [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOKzp.png). How do I calculate the normal vector (unit-length
normal, n2) for the plane that is equidistant to the two points (centered) and orthogonal to the line between these two points? I.e. P3-P2 = P2-P1 and n2 orthogonal to P3-P1.

Comment: Is P3-P1 orthogonal to the plane as it appears from your image? If so, there exists no such vector, because any normal vector to the plane will be parallel to P3-P1

Comment: wrwrwr: Thanks for your response. I was thinking the same, but wasn't sure either. Can anyone confirm it, please?
Gosha: Yes, P3-P1 is orthogonal to the plane. I'm not sure if I understand why such a vector wouldn't exist.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread `that is equidistant to the two points `, thought that it refers to the vector and that you are seeking a vector that is orthogonal to both P3-P1 and the plane

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really much calculation that you need. You have to consider the normal vector for that plane doesn't really have anything to do with being equidistant from points P1 and P3. You may want to place the base of the vector at that point, but it doesn't actually have any effect on the vector since vectors only specify a direction and magnitude, not a point in space.

So to get the vector, you just take the position vectors of P1 and P3 -- let them be V1 and V3. The normal vector is then the difference of those two vectors divided by that magnitude:

```
normal = (V3 - V1) / magnitude(V3 - V1)
```

For future reference, this is a bit off-topic for this site and should be over at the [Math SE site](https://math.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

As midpoint of the line from `P1` to `P3`, one computes `P2 = 0.5*(P1+P3)`.

The orthogonal plane to the line from P1 to P3 has trivially `P3-P1` as an orthogonal vector and thus as a normal vector to the plane. `n` can be its unit normalized vector.

The equation of the orthogonal plane is

```
dot( X, P3-P1 ) = dot(P2, P3-P1) = 0.5*(dot(P3,P3)-dot(P1,P2)).
```